# Плагин JCAROUSEL работает в IE7?

Tags: jquery, css, javascript

Этот плагин должен работать в IE7, или это я накосячил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он работает, но с ошибками: [Ошибки карусели в IE7](http://forum.searchengines.ru/showthread.php?t=592606) Ещё есть [ссылка на скачивание скина для IE7](http://forum.searchengines.ru/attachment.php?attachmentid=81720&d=1295162631)